# Shadow-layer around a PopupWindow, preferably programatically

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout, android-popupwindow, shading

I'm looking for the easiest way to set a shadow layer around my PopupWindow to increase its visibility. I've looked at solutions involving making a custom-9-patch-graphic but that seems hard to customize dynamically (my PopupWindow is showing different content depending on input and such, and as such it is of different sizes). In XML its designed as a Box implemented as a RelativeLayout with transparent background.

[image: An example of shadowing]

(Some random example I found on Google. Kind of what I want though.)

Comment: shadow-layer like what? any image?

Comment: Edited post, pasted an image as example

Comment: so its is most likely 9patch, what is wrong with it?

Comment: Wouldnt it be a problem to get the 9patch to dynamically change with the PopupWindow? Or do you have any idea of how to implement this? Because now, as I said in my post, the size of my PopupWindow changes depending on what it shows.

Comment: the whole idea around 9patches is they can have different sizes and stretch only selected areas

Comment: Okay, will have another look at that then! Thanks for your answer :)